# Starting Redis on Windows failing

Tags: windows, redis, redis-windows

I'm trying to start Redis on Windows 10.  When I run `redis-server.exe` I get the following message though:

```
C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server.exe
[4680] 01 Jun 19:57:30.844 #
The Windows version of Redis allocates a memory mapped heap for sharing with
the forked process used for persistence operations. In order to share this
memory, Windows allocates from the system paging file a portion equal to the
size of the Redis heap. At this time there is insufficient contiguous free
space available in the system paging file for this operation (Windows error
0x5AF). To work around this you may either increase the size of the system
paging file, or decrease the size of the Redis heap with the --maxheap flag.
Sometimes a reboot will defragment the system paging file sufficiently for
this operation to complete successfully.

Please see the documentation included with the binary distributions for more
details on the --maxheap flag.

Redis can not continue. Exiting.
```

I've tried adding a `--maxheap` value, but this causes the application to crash and print out a crash dump:

```
C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server.exe  --maxheap 150
[6728] 01 Jun 19:57:41.063 #

=== REDIS BUG REPORT START: Cut & paste starting from here ===
[6728] 01 Jun 19:57:41.063 # Redis version: 2.8.2400
[6728] 01 Jun 19:57:41.063 # Out Of Memory allocating 16 bytes.
[6728] 01 Jun 19:57:41.094 # --- ABORT
[6728] 01 Jun 19:57:41.094 # --- STACK TRACE
redis-server.exe!LogStackTrace(c:\release\redis\src\win32_interop\win32_stacktrace.cpp:95)(0x00000016, 0x00001C1D, 0x00000000, 0x00000001)
redis-server.exe!AbortHandler(c:\release\redis\src\win32_interop\win32_stacktrace.cpp:207)(0x00000001, 0xA222916F, 0x00000000, 0xDA31C9A7)
redis-server.exe!raise(f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\winsig.c:587)(0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000010, 0x00000018)
redis-server.exe!abort(f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\abort.c:82)(0xFFE97BC0, 0x40141940, 0x00000010, 0x00000000)
redis-server.exe!redisOutOfMemoryHandler(c:\release\redis\src\redis.c:3404)(0x00000000, 0x4013FC28, 0x00001C1D, 0x0014FB80)
redis-server.exe!createSharedObjects(c:\release\redis\src\redis.c:1326)(0x4013BD44, 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000001)
redis-server.exe!initServer(c:\release\redis\src\redis.c:1733)(0x4013BD44, 0x4013BD44, 0x00000000, 0x4013BD44)
redis-server.exe!redis_main(c:\release\redis\src\redis.c:3504)(0x00490470, 0x00000000, 0x574F3E35, 0x00000000)
redis-server.exe!main(c:\release\redis\src\win32_interop\win32_qfork.cpp:1338)(0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x0034F000)
redis-server.exe!__tmainCRTStartup(f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\crt0.c:255)(0x00000000, 0x400344CC, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk(f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\crt0.c:255)(0xD9E580E0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart(f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\crt0.c:255)(0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart(f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\crt0.c:255)(0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
[6728] 01 Jun 19:57:41.172 #
=== REDIS BUG REPORT END. Make sure to include from START to END. ===

       Please report this bug by following the instructions at:

     http://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/wiki/Submitting-an-Issue

    Suspect RAM error? Use redis-server --test-memory to verify it.
```

I've tried running with the rest memory option suggested at the end of the crash dump, but this just gives me the same error as running the executable did without it:

```
C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server.exe  --test-memory
[756] 01 Jun 19:58:34.376 #
The Windows version of Redis allocates a memory mapped heap for sharing with
the forked process used for persistence operations. In order to share this
memory, Windows allocates from the system paging file a portion equal to the
size of the Redis heap. At this time there is insufficient contiguous free
space available in the system paging file for this operation (Windows error
0x5AF). To work around this you may either increase the size of the system
paging file, or decrease the size of the Redis heap with the --maxheap flag.
Sometimes a reboot will defragment the system paging file sufficiently for
this operation to complete successfully.

Please see the documentation included with the binary distributions for more
details on the --maxheap flag.

Redis can not continue. Exiting.
```

I have 14Gb of memory, so I'm finding it hard to believe it's a memory issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer after a wee bit of Google-ing:  https://gist.github.com/anthavio/38d0ba4c916ab1911a47

Instead of using the `--maxheap` option (which seems to do nothing), add the value to the config:

```
maxheap 1000000000
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Suddenly stopped working for us today, too! I am wondering if this has something to do with patches being installed today

Comment: I got this error with `maxheap` argument - __Invalid argument during startup: unknown argument: maxheap__

Comment: @ParamvirSinghKarwal did you include the `--` at the front?

Comment: Yep! I tried two approaches. 1. Putting this option in redis config file without  - - , 2. Putting this option as command line with - - . Both gave same error

Comment: @ParamvirSinghKarwal and your putting that in the config?  Is it formatted correctly?  I can't remember what format the Redis config file is.

Comment: @BanksySan Yes, i am putting it like you have shown

Comment: @ParamvirSinghKarwal I'm afraid I'm at a loss then.  Sounds like your problem might be different to mine.  I'd suggest creating a new question which details exactly what you're doing.